# Django like middleware for Zope

Tags: wsgi, zope

Is there something similar to Django Middleware in Zope? What I want is, to check and validate all the request coming to Zope server to put some constraints on them and show the response accordingly.

I have done this previously in Django using Middleware, so was hoping to get something similar for Zope as well, but could not find it.

Please suggest.

Comment: Zope 2? Zope 3? ZTK?.... be specific please

Comment: It is Zope 2, I should have mentioned that with the question.

Comment: I know this is very very late... but were you able to figure this out? I am trying the same thing...

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal No, I could not find something reliable for Zope. I had to implement a script and call that on each request to implement the feature but that was actually not something that I wanted to do :(

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal I'm sorry I didn't see your name carefully earlier... I guess you worked on the same project on which I am working right now... People here have told me about you and I saw your name in the code... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use zope.schema based libraries like formlib or z3c.form to model forms.
Widget/form generation and validation is basically kind of build-in and can be customized as needed.

Answer (score 1):

No, Zope 2 does not support WSGI middleware, at least, not out of the box.

You could try and see if [repoze.zope2](http://repoze.org/) works for your use-case, as that bolts a WSGI pipeline on top of Zope 2. Note that development for that package stopped in 2009, and the last released version only supports Zope 2.10. YMMV.

I suspect that your use-cases may be satisfied in other ways though, but you don't provide enough detail for us to help you.